# Need a non-TAB character to traverse li items in a drop-down menu

Tags: drop-down-menu

default elements in html that are tabbable are:

`<a>` , `<area>` , `<button>` , `<input>` , `<object>` , `<select>` , and `<textarea>`

If someone were to “plop” my code for drop-down menus, my tabbable elements are my `li`.

What I wish to do is select a non- TAB key to traverse my li, thus keeping the TAB key reserved by HTML

FWIW, I just let my selection of the TAB key ride ... eventually it gets to my last `li` and then tabs to **your** `<a>` or `<input>` etc. html and then proceeds to the Browser's tabbable stuff and cycles back to the beginning of my `li` items.

Not too awful I guess?

Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can give your `<li>` items a tabindex of -1 to make sure they're not focusable vith the `TAB` character, then focus the next element with Javascript using the [`HTMLElement.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) method and [`onkeyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup) event.